# Bake não encontra os arquivos da model e controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2

Estou usando o cakephp versao 2.9, para facilitar resolvi deixar todas as aplicações com um único core.
Até ai tudo ok, mas ao usar o bake para ser mais rápido ele não acha os arquivos(model,controller) na pasta do app que estou trabalhando ele fica sempre se referindo a pasta core.
Como posso resolver isso?

Meu cenario é php 5.6 instalado e definido no path do sistema, normal uso o xamp para rodar o apache e o mysql!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O Cake não usa models ou controllers para fazer o bake. Me corrija se eu estiver enganado. O que você precisa, após configurar o arquivo database.php, é mencionar a tabela na qual quer fazer o bake.

No terminal, na pasta do seu aplicativo, digite o comando:

```
bin/cake bake /*sua tabela*/ all
```

Lembrando que você já deve ter a tabela criada. Espero ter ajudado.